# Calling data with in a value within a Variable

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to display data in a string / variable (sorry I don't know the true name for it)

```
 echo "<td>"; 
    $url='http://www.google.com/';
    $pr = new PR();
    echo "$url has Google PageRank: ". $pr->get_google_pagerank($url) ;
    echo "</td>";
```

the data and class works real well on this but I cant seem to get it to work, the following code gives me errors as it looks for a domain `http://www.{$domain}/`

```
echo "<td>"; 
$url='http://www.{$domian}/';
$pr = new PR();
echo "$url has Google PageRank: ". $pr->get_google_pagerank($url) ;
echo "</td>";
```

{$domain} is data I'm pulling from a database

Any suggestions on a better title would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable values aren't interpolated when using single-quotes.

You'll have to use double-quotes if you want the actual variable value to be used:

```
$url = "http://www.{$domian}/";
```

Read more about variables in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

Alternatively,  you can [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the variable using `.`:

```
$url = 'http://www.' . $domian . '}/';
```

Or use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$url = sprintf('http://www.%s.com', $domian);
```

Comment: Thats great spritf() was the way to go the others through errors but that might because i didn't post all the code in my opening question....Good job!